# Action Result File - Filename when downloading is wrong in some cases

Tags: c#, asp.net

So this is the Code that returns the file. It is in a Method named GetMainReport.

```
var mBytes = MergePDF(formLanguage, mergedForms);
                        if (mBytes != null)
                        {
                            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                            {
                                FileName = formLanguage.FileName,
                                Inline = formLanguage.FileExtension == FileExtension.PDF
                            };

                            Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", cd.ToString());

                            AddDownloadedForm(formLanguage.Id);
                            return File(mBytes, type);
                        }
```

My Problem now is that if i go via this url:
http://localhost:8090/Library/105020.pdf
The filename when downloaded is 105020.pdf

if i use this one

http://localhost:8090/FormSearch/FormSearch/getMainReport?FormNumber=105020%20%20de

The filename is GetMainReport.pdf

any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

try this settings for ContentDisposition:

```
 var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
  {
    FileName = formLanguage.FileName,
    DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment,
    Inline = formLanguage.FileExtension == FileExtension.PDF
   };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solutuion sadly didnt work for me.

Comment: are you using “Server.Transfer”  or “response.Redirect” before that method calling?

Comment: I mean the solution would work, my Issue is that i dont want to have it as attachment but as inline.